# SQL - How to assign records based on the latest valid record?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example:

[image: Example Table]

If I wanted to assign `COLORNAME` column to be the latest valid record how would I go about doing this?

For example, `PURPLE` in row 2 is a valid record so I want row 3-9 assigned as `PURPLE`, however when `GREEN` shows up which is the next new valid record, I want row 11-15 assigned as `GREEN`.

Comment: That's not the right way to design a database.  You should be doing this transformation before you put these records into SQL. Every record should be the same type.

Comment: IF this data is already in a table, how would you establish the order to determine "latest"  or "next". Is there a column in the table that you can use for an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @JNevill It would go off of the RowID if possible, since it's the order that the raw file was sent as

Comment: @TimRoberts Unfortunately the raw file is sent like that and is automated to load in like this, so I would need to find a way to update it myself

Comment: @user3033661 That's not going to work out for ordering. There is no inherent row order, even if happenstance causes it to show up in your `SELECT` in the same order you wrote it. In snowflake, in particular, under the hood will execute your SQL in parallel, so each parallel thread is going to have a chance to return faster than its counterparts. You'll need a column within the table by which you can establish an ORDER BY in order to solve this problem (as a first step).

Comment: @JNevill If I had a unique ID column to order it by, how would I go about trying to implement the logic above?

Comment: Yes, but the "raw file" is not sent to you as an SQL database.  That's my point -- fix the data BEFORE you bring it into SQL.

Comment: @TimRoberts Unfortunately that is not an option for me or I would have done that a while ago. I cannot control or update the files that come in, I only can work on data once it has been automated into the database (loaded in), and they already said they will not be changing the format. Another question would be, is there a way I can run a SELECT to view that table with the logic mentioned above? (I have added a unique ID for the order called ID column in case that was needed)

Comment: There is ALWAYS time to fix a flawed design.  Seriously, no competent engineer would deliver data like that as an SQL table.  What you have CANNOT be made work, because rows in an SQL database are not ordered.  There is NO guarantee that row 3 will be delivered to you after row 2, and as it sits, there is no "ORDER BY" clause that could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cleaning this data before it hits the table isn't possible, which is often the case, AND assuming that there is a column in this data from which you can establish the same order as you have presented the data in your question then one option would be to use Snowflake's [`max_by()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by) function in a correlated subquery:

```
WITH yourtable AS 
(
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS times, 'Purple' AS COLORNAME, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS TYPE, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS DESCRIPTION
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(second, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),NULL, 1, 'Marker'
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(second, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),NULL, 2, 'Crayon'
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(second, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'Green', NULL, NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(second, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),NULL, 1, 'Marker'
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(second, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),NULL, 2, 'Shirt'
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX_BY(COLORNAME, times) FROM yourtable yt2 WHERE COLORNAME IS NOT NULL AND yt1.times > yt2.times) as COLORNAME,
    TYPE, 
    DESCRIPTION
FROM yourtable yt1
WHERE COLORNAME IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was what I needed!